# Get referrer of requests currently listed by status module

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, logging

Our server has on normal time 20 request/second, which can be seen constantly on server-status (status module)

Sometimes we have 800 requests/second, and all these requests are shown on server-status. We don't know the nature of the high change in number of requests. All seam valid as they are from different IP addresses.

We would like to see the referrers of these requests.
How can I see/build something that would be like this:

if server-status shows more than 500 current working requests, produce some output with referrer info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a script that calls the server status URL, parser output to get the number of requests currently processed, and if more than 500 are returned, then tail the 500 lasts lines of the combined logs of the vhost. use tools like awk WC sort etc... to produce some report.

which and easy although not really precise, that should be enough for you to get a good idea of what's going on.